# jQuery filtering plugin to output JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json

I have created a jQuery plugin to filter JSON object, Now i want to return the filtered JSON object through a variable ?

Plugin Setup :

Comment: What are you filtering ? Kind of `pop()` object ?

Comment: Setup Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/sVuzq/

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The fiddle is a good idea, but you want to provide some specifics in the question itself, too.  Also, please move the fiddle link into the question body.  Also what is the problem?  What is happening with your plugin that is not going as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
function filter_by_key(filterkey, jsonObject)
{
    var new_obj={}, total=0, filterkey=filterkey.toLowerCase();
    for(var i in obj)
    {
        var emp_st=jsonObject[i].YourFilterKeyHere.toLowerCase();
        if(emp_st==filterkey) { new_obj[i]=jsonObject[i]; total++; }
    }

    if(total>0) return new_obj;
    return false;
}
```

// Filter the data object

```
var filtered_data=filter_by_employee_state('FilterKey', YourJsonObject);
```

Json object is something like this

```
{
  "0": {
    "emp_code": "049",
    "emp_name": "Craig J Miller",
    "emp_city": "Tustin",
    "emp_state": "CA"
  },
  "1": {
    "emp_code": 050"",
    "emp_name": "Rober Greer",
    "emp_city": "Tustin",
    "emp_state": "AL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite return from `success`, so instead of working against it, you should work with it.

Define a variable that's local to the plugin like `data` and write to it after the successful ajax call.  Then, you can return *that*:

http://jsfiddle.net/sVuzq/3/

Comment: @ARK007 the JSON request doesn't actually work; you didn't provide a valid URL